# CSS Alternative to &nbsp;?

Tags: css, html, alignment

I'm trying to make a social page which will show the social feeds that my company use.
I've managed to use padding to align the feeds the correct height and bottom padding
although, I can't seem to align them with spaces in-between them.
Am I maybe better off turning social feeds into an ID then creating individual classes for each of the feeds?
If anyone wants a link:
http://surfersyard.co.uk/dev/social.php

Comment: People are downvoting your question because it's vague, and they're not interested in going to your site and plowing through the source to try and find out what you're talking about.  Post the exact code you're trying to fix into the question, be clear about the exact nature of the problem, and you'll have better results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make the three columns (containers) in separate divs (you can use the same background image adding separate background-positions for the divs), so you can align the iframes to the center of containers

Comment: Good call! Works like a charm :) Cheers buddy

Comment: No, don't mess up the things with tables :) There's no need to use tables. Check out this: http://jsfiddle.net/k7nck/
You add the social feeds to the feed divs, than add margin to the iframes if needed. If you don't want ie7 support, you can add box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; to the .feed{} and then you can play with paddings and the width and height will remain

Comment: Haha you saw me try the easy option :p I looked at the code you suggested but you use a <div class> Within another, I didn't think that was possible?

Comment: Ooooh, I see how it works now, sorry I didn't quite click in my mind when I first read over it, cheers man